Proving that the sequence of derivatives does not matter
This is a property of derivatives that often comes up in my studies/work (applied math, not theoretical). I have always taken this result for granted but am interested in learning how it can be proven:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\right) $$
Playing around with some basic derivatives definitions:
$$ \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\right)\right|_{(a,b)} = \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\right)\right|_{(a,b)} $$
$$ \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x,y+h) - g(x,y)}{h} $$
This was a bit tricky, but I try to diffrentiate again:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\right) = \lim_{k \to 0} \frac{\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x+k,y+h) - g(x+k,y)}{h} - \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x,y+h) - g(x,y)}{h}}{k} $$
Combining the limits:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\right) = \lim_{k \to 0} \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{g(x+k,y+h) - g(x+k,y)}{h} - \frac{g(x,y+h) - g(x,y)}{h}}{k} $$
Multiply both numerator and denominator by $h$:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\right) = \lim_{k \to 0} \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{g(x+k,y+h) - g(x+k,y)}{h} - \frac{g(x,y+h) - g(x,y)}{h}}{k} \cdot \frac{h}{h} $$
Simplify:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\right) = \lim_{k \to 0} \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{kh}[g(x+k,y+h) - g(x+k,y) - g(x,y+h) + g(x,y)] $$
Now, I tried to do the same thing, but reverse the order:
$$ \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = \lim_{k \to 0} \frac{g(x+k,y) - g(x,y)}{k} $$
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\right) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\lim_{k \to 0} \frac{g(x+k,y+h) - g(x,y+h)}{k} - \lim_{k \to 0} \frac{g(x+k,y) - g(x,y)}{k}}{h} $$
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\right) = \lim_{h \to 0} \lim_{k \to 0} \frac{\frac{g(x+k,y+h) - g(x,y+h)}{k} - \frac{g(x+k,y) - g(x,y)}{k}}{h} $$
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\right) = \lim_{h \to 0} \lim_{k \to 0} \frac{\frac{g(x+k,y+h) - g(x,y+h)}{k} - \frac{g(x+k,y) - g(x,y)}{k}}{h} \cdot \frac{k}{k} $$
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\right) = \lim_{h \to 0} \lim_{k \to 0} \frac{1}{hk}[g(x+k,y+h) - g(x,y+h) - g(x+k,y) + g(x,y)] $$
While I can see that both of these are equal, I am not sure how to justify that these limits will converge in general (i.e. the $hk$ term in the denominator goes away). I can see this for a specific functions, but can this be show in general?

You need some sort of continuity for this interchange to hold, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Schwarz.27_theorem for example, there are generalisations, of course.

See this answer for a specific function whose mixed second derivatives are not the same when the order is reversed. So no proof will work without extra assumptions.
